# Udev rule for USB device not triggering

Tags: 14.04, udev

I'm struggling to create a udev rule for my son's camera. There are some solutions online already which may or may not work. However, what I'm more intereted in is understanding why this doesn't work.

I've queried the device once it's plugged in as follows:

```
ubuntu-laptop:~$ udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdc

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host26/target26:0:0/26:0:0:1/block/sdc':
    KERNEL=="sdc"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="532480"
    ATTR{stat}=="       2        0       16   186156        0        0        0        0        0   186156   186156"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}=="media_change"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="2000"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{removable}=="1"
    ATTR{capability}=="51"
    ATTR{events_async}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host26/target26:0:0/26:0:0:1':
    KERNELS=="26:0:0:1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{rev}=="2.12"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="3"
    ATTRS{model}=="SYSTEM          "
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x22"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x28"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x1"
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="VTECH   "
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host26/target26:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target26:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host26':
    KERNELS=="host26"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-1.2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2':
    KERNELS=="2-1.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0f88"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="16"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="c0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0001"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="140850300000000"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="255"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="VTech"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="3701"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="Kidizoom"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="8"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="938"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="261"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"
    ATTRS{irq}=="23"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1025"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000000f"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x3b34"
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0487"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Every post I read on udev directs you to this site: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#udevinfo

Looking at that, I created the following rule (making sure I picked attributes from the same parent device):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="VTech", ATTRS{product}=="Kidizoom", SYMLINK+="toy_cam"
```

I save the rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/toycam.rules. I then reload the rules and plug in the camera and yet there's no "/dev/toy_cam".

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I'd love to understand why it's not working.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: what happens when you mount it manually?
`sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc /mnt`

Answer (score 1):

Use `lsusb` to list the basic attributes of your device. Once you have it, you can use the VendorID and the ProductID to make the rule. For example, the output of `lsub`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
```

Take a look on this numbers: `8087:0024`

These are the vendorId and the productId, so, your rule could look like:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024", MODE = "0660", GROUP="whell"
```

In the GROUP part, make sure your user is in that group, for example, if you want your user to be part of the group whell, run:

```
sudo usermod -aG whell <user>
```

where `<user>` is your username

Remember, this rule must be in the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory and must have 0664 permissions. The name of the file could be like:

```
30-Camera.rules
```

Then use:

```
sudo chmod 0644 30-Camera.rules
```

To make it work. Finally, reboot your PC.

For more information about udev rules writing, take a look at: [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

Comment: From your proposed solution, there is no need to reboot. `udev`rules take effect immediately upon writing the file that contains them.

Comment: The same I tough, but that did not worked immediately in my case. Is weird I know. However, thanks for your comment.